# Boot trouble-shooting

Tags: boot

I am new to ubuntu...
Last time i was deleting many unwanted personal files...
But i think i have mistakenly deleted a system folder too...n i dont know what it was... And i am not sure whether that folder was a system folder or not...
After that i shut down my laptop and now when i try to switch it on a message is displayed like never before :
"GNU grub version blah blah(outside the box)

(inside the box)
okay here is the details of the screen while booting from where i dont know what to do...

```
=====================================================
GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
-----------------------------------------------------
Ubuntu with Linux3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Ubuntu with Linux3.2.0-29-generic-pae (recovery mode)
previous linux version
Memory Test (memtest86+)
Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console115200)
------------------------------------------------------
```

and below the box the message is as:

```
use the up and down arrow keys to select which entry is highlighted
press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit commands before booting, or 'c' for a command line
=======================================================
```

choosing first option leads me to a blank screen with a blinking cursor where i cant type anything...just a black screen and blinking cursor and nothing more....

choosing 2nd option i.e. recovery mode leads me to a screen where many codes are generated...

(sorry i could not upload a image due to points issue)
and in that page after many codes everything is said "...done"
but at bottom
it shows error message

```
-----------------------------------------------
[3.28538] init: Failed to spawn friendly recovery pre-start process :unable to execute: No such file or directory
[3.28538] init: Failed to spawn friendly recovery posy-stop process :unable to execute: No such file or directory
_
-------------------------------------------------
```

and then again a black screen with some texts and blinking cursor...
:(

choosing third option takes me to a screen as:

```
======================================

Ubuntu with Linux3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Ubuntu with Linux3.2.0-29-generic-pae (recovery mode)

======================================
```

at the same place again and everything takes place similarly...

i do not know what to do...
please help...

(box closes
)
choose one of the options"

i didnt understood anything but... No option leads me to the OS
choosing my normal ubuntu version shows up a black screen with out anything... Jst "_" at the top left and nothing all...
Choosing recovery mode generates many codes
blah blah blah done
blah blah blah done
blah blah blah done
n then it stops and nothing works after that....
i dont know what to do...
Do i need to try boot repair disk method...
Or i need to reinstall OS...
If i reinstall the OS then will i loose my datas or i wont...
Please sumbody help me...

update:
i ve tried boot repair disk
n it gave me URL hope it will help...
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5849279/

Comment: I am more than willing to help but you need to enable us to do so. For anyone here to be able to answer we most times need the actual message. The usage of the word "blah" does not help so kindly change your question to the actual messages. If need be take a screenshot with a camera from a phone and upload it somewhere, toss the link in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback...
I ll keep that in mind...
It will take me some time but i ll try to do that...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are new to Linux at all... First basic truth you have to know: you should never do primary login as root and never use root as home user account! It is the fastest way to kill system, especially for new users. But in home user folder you can do ANYTHING.

Set password to your root account and use it with caution. Ubuntu has a lot of scripts to do system tasks, use them instead of manual hacking. Now simpliest solution is to reinstall Ubuntu completely without formatting hard drive. This will keep all your data and restore system files. Though if you placed your data in wrong location like `/etc`, `/usr`, you have to move it in `/home/user` directory before you proceed.

Or you can try to restore files you have deleted using [this instruction](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693). But before you have to choose recovery mode and drop to root shell prompt. I also recommend you to modify the script to make it operate faster:

```
apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall `dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)'`
```

Answer (score 0):

well, choose that recovery option and let it load

A list of options will come up before you out of which choose:-

> Drop to root terminal

A cursor will be blinking after a text (root@yourpc$ ), type

```
sudo update-grub
```

and press enter

after the process completes, type

```
 sudo reboot
```